# How to make the output of neural evolution to be only binary numbers?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I used Gym Retro to try NEAT in Pong Atari 2600.

The game has 2 binary numbers as input to control the paddle, but the neural evolution function is giving me real numbers

Instead of getting list of 0 or 1 like [0,1], it gives me 0.12451 or 123.3123. This cannot be input and i have no idea how to fix neat's output to only binary.

How can I make neural network to control paddle?

```
import retro     
import numpy as np          
import neat         
import pickle      
import os
import multiprocessing
import cv2
#def eval_genomes(genomes, config):

runs_per_net=5

def eval_genome(genome, config):
    env = retro.make(game='Pong-Atari2600', state='Start')
    env.reset()
    ob, rew, done, info = env.step(env.action_space.sample())
    inx = int(ob.shape[0]/8)
    iny = int(ob.shape[1]/8)
    done=False

    net=neat.nn.recurrent.RecurrentNetwork.create(genome,config)

    fitness=0

    while not done:
        env.render()
        ob = cv2.resize(ob, (inx, iny))
        ob = cv2.cvtColor(ob, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        ob = np.reshape(ob, (inx, iny))

        imgarray = np.ndarray.flatten(ob)
        imgarray = np.interp(imgarray, (0, 254), (-1, +1))
        actions = net.activate(imgarray)
        print(actions)
        ob, rew, done, info = env.step(actions)

        score=info['score1']

    print(fitness)
    return(fitness)


def run():
    local_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    config_path = os.path.join(local_dir, 'pong_config')
    config = neat.Config(neat.DefaultGenome, neat.DefaultReproduction,
                         neat.DefaultSpeciesSet, neat.DefaultStagnation,
                         config_path)

    pop = neat.Population(config)
    stats = neat.StatisticsReporter()
    pop.add_reporter(stats)
    pop.add_reporter(neat.StdOutReporter(True))

    pe = neat.ParallelEvaluator(4, eval_genome)
    winner = pop.run(pe.evaluate)

    # Save the winner.
    with open('winner-feedforward', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(winner, f)

    print(winner)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

score everything above 1 with a fitness of 0 and that should naturally select only those genomes that yield answers between 0 and 1 or take the output and run it through either RELU or a [sigmoid function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) before sending it to the game